# Rest API for bugzilla

Tags: api, rest, bugzilla

We are setting up bugzilla for issue tracking within our startup. I want to know if Bugzilla supports REST based API's for filing/searching bugs. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

[Bugzilla REST API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify your installation Bugzilla comes with an XML-RPC interface ([docs](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html)). Although updating bugs is not supported until 4.0, creating, searching and adding comments are all supported.

Comment: A javascript example of how to create a request would be helpful, my first look at that page (before coming here) I couldn't even tell what language it was supposed to be in.

Comment: The interface isn't JavaScript specific see http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec there is also a JSON-RPC (http://json-rpc.org/) interface as well. http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Server/JSONRPC.html

Comment: Well apparently it is all moot, because our bugzilla server (3.6) doesn't even have support for XML or JSON RPC...